# Responsive elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following code and I'm trying to make all the elements next to each other be responsive when the size of the window is changed. I don't mind them getting smaller as long as they stay next to each other. My idea was to use media queries but wasn't very successful in that area.

HTML:

```
<div  style="float:left">
    <div >Testing Responsivness</div>
</div>
<div  style="float:left">
    <input type="number" class="theInput" min="1" />
    <label ><strong class="q-d-currency">&nbsp; $ </strong> </label>
</div>
<div >
    <button type="submit" ></button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rft1y94v/

Comment: Please, post your jsfiddle.

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: Nothing is actually wrong I would just like to leave all elements next to each other when the window size is decreased instead of them going under each other..even if that emans I'll make them smaller

Comment: use percents (%) : button { width: 30%} and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this fiddle... Is this what you want?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tw5kw0ey/)

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="block1">
        <div style="display:inline-block;" >Testing Responsivness</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
        <input type="number" class="theInput" min="1" />
        <label ><strong class="q-d-currency">&nbsp; $ </strong> </label>
    </div>
    <div class="block3">
        <button type="submit" >submit</button>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.block1{
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.block2{
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

.block3{
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple usage of `media query`. When you resize windows the `width` of columns will be reduced. I think you could not use media query because of inline style.

According to [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp):

> Generally speaking we can say that all the styles will "cascade" into
>   a new "virtual" style sheet by the following rules, where number one
>   has the highest priority:
>
> Inline style (inside an HTML element) External and internal style
>   sheets (in the head section) Browser default

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/rft1y94v/3/)